# Not seeing any speedup when multiprocessing c++ code in python?

Tags: python, c++, performance, multiprocessing

I have some python code, which relies on a piece of c++ code that essentially does a large tree search. I need to run this tree search n times in a for loop and since each iteration was taking several second I figured this would be an obvious place to add some multiprocessing in python to speed things up. My multiprocessing is fairly standard:

```
        with Pool() as pool:
            probs = pool.starmap(self._probs_multi, zip(self.features, self.scales, repeat(labels), repeat(nr_classes)))
```

I can see that when I run it, I get n cores that operate at 100% load (when n is smaller than my number of cores), as opposed to the sequential case where I had 1 core operating at 100% load. However the total runtime of the for loop is still taking the same amount of time!

The c++ library is right now loaded using something like this:

```
import ctypes
import numpy.ctypeslib as ctl 
libfile = os.path.dirname(__file__) + '/km_dict_lib.so'
lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(libfile)

py_km_tree_multi = lib.build_km_tree_multi
# say which inputs the function expects
py_km_tree_multi.argtypes = [ctl.ndpointer(ctypes.c_double, flags="C_CONTIGUOUS"),
                             ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_int, 
                             ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_int,
                             ctypes.c_bool,
                             ctl.ndpointer(ctypes.c_double, flags="C_CONTIGUOUS")]
py_km_tree_multi(image, rows, cols, channels, n_im, 
                     self.patch_size, self.number_layers, self.branching_factor, 
                     number_training_patches, self.normalization, self.tree)
```

I can think of two reasons why the sequential run is as fast as the multiprocessor run. The first reason is that the job is not actually cpu bound but memory bound instead, I guess this could be the case for a tree search I am not really that experienced with them, but if this is the case it seems strange to me that all n cores are having 100% load which to me suggest it should be cpu bound?
The other option is that somehow the multiprocessing isn't actually working when the python script is calling an external c++ function or that my naive approach for this is insufficient.

Does anyone have any insight into how I can move forward with this and figure out what is wrong?

Comment: Read the code to this "km_dict_lib" library and see if it does some kind of synchronization?

Comment: There's a popular myth that using two CPUs for any task will get it done twice as fast. This is not true.

Comment: What does *self._probs_multi* do?

Comment: @Botje As far as I can see there should be no synchronization in the library, I am not 100% sure since I have never programmed in c++, but from my understanding of the code and the overall algorithm it should be just be a fancy sequence of lookups when I do the tree search in parallel. The actual tree was built sequentially earlier.

Comment: @CtrlZ This function just takes the input parameter and uses them to call the c++ code and finally it returns the output from the tree search which in this case is a probability map.

Comment: I think when processors are waiting for data (on memory bound application) they will show 100% load, because they are "stuck" waiting, can't do anything else at the time. Maybe you can create less data-transfer-consuming test? You could make all cores calculate the very same thing, they will use the same memory.

Comment: @Tue How big is the probability map? If it's large, you'll be consuming a lot of CPU due to serialisation [of the response]

Comment: @LucasM.Uriarte OP is clear that it's multiprocessing and **not** multithreading

Comment: @CtrlZ The probability map is 4000 x 4000, so I wouldn't imagine that it should take a lot of time. But I suppose it does add up with the overhead.

Comment: @Tue How many CPUs do you have and what is the length of *self.features* ?

Comment: @CtrlZ I have 1 cpu, with 10 physical cores and 20 logical cores. n=len(self.features) can have various values, but the examples I have mostly been testing have been with n=3, but I have also tried with 5 and 10 for instance. And I am generally seeing the same thing in all cases.

Comment: I think the problem might be due to the rather large tree that exist in the code and probably gets duplicated to all processes. I will try tomorrow to see whether I can get that to work with shared memory like shown here: https://mingze-gao.com/posts/python-shared-memory-in-multiprocessing/ I will report back tomorrow.

Comment: Are you "building the tree" for every call to `_props_multi`? The canonical response to this is a simple threading or forking server. That way you only pay for "building the tree" once.

Comment: @Botje I am 99% positive I am not building the tree at every call. However, the more I look at the c++ code the more I think that the tree or at least some tmp variables connected to the tree are modified whenever I search the tree, which likely means that the overall tree object is modified, which is likely why the whole multiprocessing is failing. I guess the c++ code really wasn't written in a way to allow multiprocessing.

Comment: That is indeed far out of scope of this qestion. Suggest you ask a follow-up question then.

Answer (score -5):

You are facing the GIL (Global Instruction Lock) issue. Most Python implementations have this global lock so the interpreter essentially runs sequentially. To my knowledge, the only way to achieve parallelism with Python is to use it only to dispatch foreign jobs that can, in themselves, run in parallel. In your case, the zip call is going to be waited-on to finish before the loop advances to the next iteration. You might need to change your payload code with a little wrapper to dispatch the original payload, and quickly return to the loop. Regards.

Alright. I am actually looking at the source code of the interpreter. Indeed the GIL is not a global mutex, it is just an atomic uint8. But it could have been, Right? In that case the threads would have contended even across processes. Okay. It isn’t the case.

About parallelism having nothing to do with the GIL. Sorry, it would, if the code had callbacks. These callbacks are comming back to the main process to be executed. So things are not quite as simple and clear. Alright. The OP doesn’t have any obvious callbacks. Or does he, indirectly?

But onto another possible problem. It is not the GIL, but it may be the semlock used to guard access to shared objects.

Or do you think I am wrong again and you’d want to down vote me all the way out of this forum?

Comment: This answer is not clear. If he is using different process, the GIL should not affect. The GIL only affects multithreading, since thread share memory and objects. Process have a separate memory an object of everything thus are not affected by the GIL. Also would be good you correct the name of GIL (Global interpreter Lock) not (Global Instruction Lock).

Comment: Not relevant for multiprocessing